# Understanding of a formula with matrix summation

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, matrix-equations

We are a quite a few students at in the class struggling to compute this would anyone be able to help? Also note --> ' means transpose.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sorry for the misunderstanding, when I said that it is not possible to divide by T since it is a matrix, i meant that since the sum after 1/T is a matrix how can you divide the matrix by T.

Also could someone clarify the length of T since I might have misunderstood. I thought T would be 3 do to the number of values in e.

Comment: According to what you posted, T is 3, which looks suspiciously like a number.  Which part of the brown are you having trouble with?  It's much like the red part you have, instead you're using two different vectors from your list instead of the same one twice.

Comment: I thought large the would be the number of inputs in this case 3, so it would sum from 1 to 3. Might be that I am wrong.

Comment: $T$ has to be the length of the vector $e$, and the number of vectors $x_i$. As tabstop says, it is not a matrix. If your problem is with dividing a matrix *by* $T$; you do this by dividing each entry by $T$.

Comment: I edited my question in the bottom.

Comment: It was said '$T$ is the *length* of vector $e$', but here vector was rather meant as a tuple. So the term '*dimension*' would have been better to use. Anyway, $T$ is still $3$.

Comment: Well I am struggling with how the 1/T works with the matrix I have calculated already. I have also problem with the j, does it go from i to 2 or?

Comment: In the calculation that I have made red, do I multiply (1/3) with each matrix before I sum up the matrix?